# Format words using pure css

Tags: html, css

I have some data which needs to be formatted and I want to format it by using only css no javascript nothing.
So the question is I have this sample string:

> Home - Office

Expected Output:

> [image]

I want to format these words using css without inserting any div. Like the code can be in this way:

```
someData.push(`${origin.code} - ${destination.code}`); // code coming from the store file
<div>{value}</div> //prints the above code value here and this is from the js file
```

and the output will be like the above mention in the blockquote. But again I have some random list getting generated via push code. I don't want to use the div here. Is there a way by using css we can space them? Also I want to hide the " - " hyphen symbol. I have used word spacing but then again it's hardcode and also creates problem when resizing the window the last text stays at the original position it doesn't resize.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Besides a few special cases (:first-letter, :first-line, ...) you can not format “parts of text” alone directly with CSS, you can only target _elements_. In this particular situation you could probably justify the text to get the desired left/right alignment of those two words - but the dash in the middle would still show, hardly any way around that (other than trying to cover it up using some absolute positioned element roughly in the middle of that area or something.) If you want more than that, you will most likely need to modify the structure first.

Answer (score 1):

[`text-align: justify-all;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) (MDN) would probably solve your problem with justification but it's unsupported.

AFAIK you need ONE child element, at least for hiding that dash and then you can use it for justifying those 2 words too.

➡️ **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/yqJwYj)**

```css
body {
  max-width: 30rem;
}

p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  outline: 1px dotted darkred;
}

.case2 > span:first-child {
  display: none;
}

.case3 > span:first-child {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!-- node texts can be justified but you need some flex items too -->
<p>Home - <span>Office</span></p>

<!-- the 1st span can be hidden -->
<p class="case2">Home <span>-</span> <span>Office</span></p>

<!-- the dash-span can be both hidden and make node texts be justified -->
<p class="case3">Home <span>-</span> Office</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, everyone...I have solved the problem. I had to use javascript. I had to split  the value which is present in JS file and then assign it to a variable and use that variable to print the values, which is something like this:

`let valueSplit = value.split(/-(.+)/);

<span>{valueSplit[0]}</span>
<span>{valueSplit[1]}</span>`

and it worked. I just wana know, if we can do this just by css....